# Triangle inequality for L2 norm

Tags: measure-theory

I am posed with a problem as below.

Let $X$ be the collection of real valued functions that are measurable on $[0,1]$. For a given number $p\geq 1$ define the $L^p$ norm by $(\int_0^1|f(x)|^p)^\frac{1}{p}$.

I need to show for $p=1,2$ that this defines a semi norm on $X$. $p=1$ was simple as was all of $p=2$ except for the triangle inequality. I am having trouble proving the triangle inequality for this. Could anybody nudge me into the right direction or am I simply over thinking it? I think I can prove it for vectors but I'm not sure how to tackle it with integrals. Right now I can only use relatively basic results because this in for an introductory measure theory course.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

$$
\int (f+g)^2 = \int f^2 + \int g^2 + 2\int fg
$$Now via the Schwartz inequality:
$$
\int fg \le \sqrt{\int f^2} \sqrt{\int g^2}
$$so

$$
\int (f+g)^2 \le \int f^2 + \int g^2 + 2\sqrt{\int f^2} \sqrt{\int g^2}
= \left( \sqrt{\int f^2} + \sqrt{\int g^2}\right)^2
$$Eventually:
$$
|f+g|_{L^2}\le |f|_{L^2}+|g|_{L^2}
$$

Answer (score 3):

For $1\le p \le \infty$, it's just Minkowski inequality, See:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality