# Is this a metric in the space of continuous martingales?

Tags: metric-spaces, martingales, stochastic-analysis

In my stochastic analysis class we've defined the following local convergence metric in the space of continuous square-integrable martingales
$$m(M,N) = \sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n} \Big(1\wedge \big(E(M_n-N_n)^2\big)^{1/2}\Big)$$

My issue is mainly with the triangle inequality. I can see how we could prove a relaxed version of the triangle inequality with
$$m(M,N) \leq \sqrt 2 m(M,P) + \sqrt 2 m(P,N)$$
using the fact that $(a+b)^2 \leq 2a^2 + 2b^2$, but I don't see how to obtain the usual triangle inequality. Am I missing something, or am I indeed correct?

Thank you.

Comment: You have the triangle inequality for the $L^2$ norm of $M_n - P_n + P_n - N_n$. Instead of (presumably) bounding $(M_n - P_n + P_n - N_n)^2$ using the inequality you gave just apply the triangle inequality here directly.

Comment: @nobody true, I should've thought of that, the same problem would arise in $L^2$ spaces if I was right. Thank you. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By applying the triangle inequality for the $L^2$ norm we see 
\begin{align*} & m(M,N) = \sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n} \Big(1\wedge \big(E(M_n-N_n)^2\big)^{1/2}\Big)  \\ & \leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n} \Big(1\wedge \big(\big(E(M_n-P_n)^2\big)^{1/2} + \big(E(N_n-P_n)^2\big)^{1/2} \big)\Big)  \\ & \leq \sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n} \Big(1\wedge \big(E(M_n-P_n)^2\big)^{1/2} \big) + \sum^\infty_{n=1} 2^{-n} \Big(1\wedge \big(E(N_n-P_n)^2\big)^{1/2} \big) \\ & = m(M,P) + m(N,P) \end{align*}
giving the result.

Comment: To see why the triangle inequality works for the $L^2$-norm, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710254/triangle-inequality-for-l2-norm).